# Edit original Nautilus context menu

Tags: contextmenu, nautilus

Does anyone know a way to simplify the standard context (right click) menu in Nautilus? I am making a very simplified interface for people who don't use computers very often, and I want to use Nautilus as File Manager. I have added some actions to the context menu using nautilus-action, but I want to remove the standard Copy/Paste/Create Folder/Create link and pretty much all the rest. I haven't found any XML or other config file on my system, I have used grep on Nautilus' sources to find where it is, because I suspect it is hard coded, but no joy so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The menu schema is located in the file nautilus-directory-view-ui.xml within Nautilus' sources if you are compiling it, or in **/usr/share/nautilus/ui/**. If nautilus is already installed, use "nautilus -q && nautilus" in a terminal to apply changes.